# update data via cron in cartodb

Tags: carto, geometry, import

I want to automaticaly insert/update points via cron in cartodb.
I am using SQL API.

How can I generate the_geom row via sql api in WKB format without web-interface?

Like this:

`0101000020E61000004260E5D0224F464078D503E621074440`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, that's a geometry in the WKB (Well known binary) format, but you don't need to use this format in order to generate the geometries, there are other ways. :-)

A request like this one will work (uses ST_MakePoint):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (the_geom, name) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($LONGITUDE,$LATITUDE), 4326), 'John')
```

Being latitude and longitude your variables/values. There are other functions that you can use too to generate a geometry object from text, such as ST_GeomFromGeoJSON (http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) , ST_GeomFromKML (http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromKML.html), ST_GeomFromText (http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is relevant code snippet:

```
insert into table2 (the_geom,name,description) values(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.7490111  55.801113)', 4326),'test','test descr')
```